# WP7 Bing Map Id from windows store

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps, windows-store

I've made a map control in my windows phone 7 app and now I want to publish it on windows store. It works with developer Bing id. I've started the procedure and got the Bing map id from windows store. What am I to do in order for maps to work when application is published? Am I only to change the developers bing map id with the one I got from store?

Also can I test the app with the win store bing map id before I finish the publishing and how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For WP7 you should create a Bing Maps account/key and use this key to authenticate your map. The same key can be used in development as what you would use for when the application is released. You can find information on how to create a bing maps account and key here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg605201.aspx